# Linux - Get to Shell before other driver boot up

Tags: linux, shell, boot

How can I edit my startup scripts in linux so that I get to the login screen as soon as possible? I want all the other accessories (such as Bluetooth, Wifi, Ethernet) drivers to run ONCE I have gotten to the login screen and can now log into shell.

The only thing I can think of is to change the `rmnologin` order so that it runs before anything else. Is that a good idea?

Comment: In the future, please post this sort of question to http://unix.stackexchange.com OR http://askubuntu.com . Thanks and Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dependency based init tool like systemd or startpar, then if you still don't have prompt fast enugh dependency reasearch (or trial and error) would be in order. Also set your bios to fast boot. You can also boot into single user mode then change run level later if you want.

Comment: How do I set the BIOS to fastboot on linux?

Comment: It's nothing to do with Linux, before linux there is Grub, and before that there is your BIOS, when you reboot your computer you can press a key like F12 to enter BIOS settings. Sometimes there is a fastboot option that will get you to Grub faster.... you can also disable the wait in Grub if it is making you wait before booting Linux.